# tooltip.js popper.js usage example

Tags: jquery, popper.js

As not very proficient in javascript I don't understand the [tooltip.js](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-documentation.html) documentation at all. Why do the not include an example for people like me?

Ho do I have to install this library in order to work correctly?

1. I add `tooltip.js` to `webpack` (installed via npm)
2. Then I do `import tooltip from 'tooltip.js';`
3. Then what?

I tried to use the code from [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) :

```
<p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</p>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

But I don't actually use bootstrap so the error is: TypeError:

> $(...).tooltip is not a function

There is some example code on [their example page](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html) which doesn't really help:

```
new Tooltip(referenceElement, {
    placement: 'top', // or bottom, left, right, and variations
    title: "Top"
});
```

What is `referenceElement` ? Is it the class of the element I whish to trigger?

I imagine something like this:

```
<p title="xyz" data-toggle="tooltip">hello</p>
```

And then write the javascript somewhat like this???

```
new Tooltip('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', {
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

That certainly does not work. It returns the error:

> TypeError: reference.addEventListener is not a function

How? Why? A little Codepen: https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/ZowqdM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation you must call tooltips like this

```
new Tooltip(referenceElement, {
    placement: 'top', // or bottom, left, right, and variations
    title: "Top"
});
```

so, if you want make all element with [data-toggle="tooltip"] call tooltips js you can do like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' ).each(function() {
    new Tooltip($(this), {
      placement: 'top',
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How did you import 'Tooltip' in the js file?

Comment: like this `import Tooltip from 'tooltip.js';`

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("is-success")[0];
    var instance = new Tooltip(trigger,{
        title: trigger.getAttribute('data-tooltip'),
        trigger: "hover",
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js"></script>
<button class="button is-success" data-tooltip="Click Here">Hover Me</button>
```